# paypal configuration in magento

Tags: magento, paypal

no purchase order or invoice is sent to the client when paying by credit card. when the payment is made through paypal transaction, it displays an error message "The transaction was declined by paypal gateway"

Answer (score 0):

**Why PayPal Declines transaction?**

A processor decline indicates that the customer’s bank has refused the transaction request. Sometimes you can tell why it was declined by reading the response code, but only the customer's bank can confirm the specific reason. Here are a few of the most common ones:

- Incorrect credit card number or expiration date
- Insufficient funds
- Some banks will reject charges based on location
- Some banks will reject charges based on their own fraud rules

You may also see the  [PayPal decline article](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/transactions/declines).

Also you can follow [PayPal advanced error message "Payment has been declined. Please try again"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58857/paypal-advanced-error-message-payment-has-been-declined-please-try-again)